# FacesMessage not displayed when deploying portlet on WAS 8.5.5.13

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, websphere

I'm migrating some portlets from WPS 7 to WAS 8.5.5.13, so that I can use my own framework instead of Websphere portal. Migrated portlets work on WAS 8.5.5.13 with some deficiency. Faces messages are not displayed as it should be (as they are when running portlet on WPS 7). A warning is logged:

```
WARNING: There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
```

I'm currently not even sure where to look for to solve my issue. Any suggestion why are messages displayed when running portlets on WPS 7, but not when running on WAS 8.5.5.13?

PS: I haven't posted any code. If any code/configuration could be helpful to solve my issue, please let me know.

Comment: Does your app have a way to render those messages, eg. h:messages or p:messages?  WPS might have been rendering those messages itself.

Comment: @wtlucy of course, I'm using Primefaces component: `<p:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="false" showIcon="false" />`.

Comment: That component will only render messages with a `null` client ID due to the `globalOnly="true"`.  There might be messages with valid client IDs that are still falling through - you can try to find them removing the `globalOnly` param and adding `redisplay="false"`.

Comment: @wtlucy yes, it will render messages with `null` client ID, that is my goal. But I have no idea why it's not working on WAS, while on WPS7 messages are displayed as expected. Component (and all the other code) is the same. If I remove  `globalOnly="true"`, those messages of course won't be displayed.

Comment: Using an `h:messages` fails too?